# Settings API saving options

Tags: php, wordpress, settings

I'm getting my head slowly round the settings api in WordPress and I'm struggling slightly. I want to have a bunch of options that a user can populate and when they click save have it edit the options array. I can't seem to save an option in the database and my code just goes to options.php where an error says ERROR: options page not found. I know I'm doing something wrong but I just can't see it (after two evenings).

My code so far is:

```
register_setting( 'cjd_options', 'twitter', 'cjd_validate_twitter' );

add_settings_field( 'twitter', 'Twitter URL', 'cjd_twitter_input', 'cjd_social', 'cjd_social_section' );

add_settings_section( 'cjd_social_section', '', 'cjd_admin_options_callback', 'cjd_social' );

function cjd_twitter_input() {

$options = get_option( 'cjd_options' );
echo '<input type="text" class="widefat" id="twitter" name="cjd_options[twitter]" value="'. $options['twitter'] .'" />';

}
function cjd_validate_twitter() {

$twitter = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['twitter'] );

$twitter = trim($twitter);

$twitter = update_option( 'cjd_options', array('twitter' => $twitter) );

return $twitter;

}
```

Form looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="options.php">

 <?php settings_fields( 'cjd_social_section' ); ?>

 <?php do_settings_sections( 'cjd_social' ); ?>   

<?php submit_button(); ?>
```

Any help would be great.